# Всё ли здесь правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Все хотят жить хорошо,
Но не все дадут "хорошо" жить другим

Comment: Обратите внимание на повторяющуюся ошибку: Вы уже не первый раз пишете большую букву после запятой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вы должны для себя решить: это одно предложение или два?

Если одно, тогда пишем так:
**Все хотят жить хорошо, но** [с маленькой буквы] **не все дают "хорошо жить" другим.**

Если два предложения, то так:
**Все хотят жить хорошо** [точка]. **Но не все дают "хорошо жить" другим.**
Союз в начале предложения — это одно из средств литературной выразительности, подчеркивания того, о чем Вы говорите.

2. В конце любого предложения ставится знак препинания, обозначающий, собственно, это окончание. В Вашем случае — точка. Кстати, можно и восклицательный знак поставить. (Но не все дают "хорошо жить" другим!)
3. В кавычки надо взять все выражение — "хорошо жить", чтобы не возникло двусмысленности ("хорошо" = плохо).
4. По смыслу, как я ощущаю, глагол "дадут" (будущее время) лучше использовать в форме настоящего времени — "дают".